# Disabling suggestions works only for certain fields - HTML

Tags: html, autocomplete

We have a basic registration `jsp` with fields for First name, Last name, Email-id, Password and Confirm password. To disable suggestions in controls we tried `autocomplete="off"` in form and in individual controls, suggestions were disabled for First name and Last name, but for Email-id suggestions are still coming. This is the code

```
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<c:set var="contextPath" value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}"/>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Create an account</title>

        <link href="${contextPath}/resources/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="${contextPath}/resources/css/common.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>

    <body>

        <div class="container">

            <form:form id="regForm" method="POST" autocomplete="off" class="form-signin">
                <div class="jumbotron text-center">
                    <h1>Register your account here with your Email id</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <spring:bind path="firstName">
                        <div class="form-group ${status.error ? 'has-error' : ''}">
                            <form:input type="text" path="firstName" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" placeholder="First name"></form:input> <!-- Suggestions disabled -->
                            <form:errors path="firstName"></form:errors>
                        </div>
                    </spring:bind>

                    <spring:bind path="lastName">
                        <div class="form-group ${status.error ? 'has-error' : ''}">
                            <form:input type="text" path="lastName" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Last name"></form:input> <!-- Suggestions disabled -->
                            <form:errors path="lastName"></form:errors>
                        </div>
                    </spring:bind>

                    <spring:bind path="username">
                        <div class="form-group ${status.error ? 'has-error' : ''}">
                            <form:input type="email" path="username" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Email id"></form:input> <!-- Suggestions not disabled -->
                            <form:errors path="username"></form:errors>
                        </div>
                    </spring:bind>

                    <spring:bind path="password">
                        <div class="form-group ${status.error ? 'has-error' : ''}">
                            <form:input type="password" path="password" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Password"></form:input>
                            <form:errors path="password"></form:errors>
                        </div>
                    </spring:bind>

                    <spring:bind path="passwordConfirm">
                        <div class="form-group ${status.error ? 'has-error' : ''}">
                            <form:input type="password" path="passwordConfirm" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Confirm your password"></form:input>
                            <form:errors path="passwordConfirm"></form:errors>
                        </div>
                    </spring:bind>
                </div>

                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-success" type="submit">Register</button>
                    <a href="${contextPath}/loginEmployee">Back to login</a>
                </div>

            </form:form>

        </div>

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="${contextPath}/resources/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

[image: Screen Shot]

We tried the above code in plain HTML but the effect was same

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Create an account</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <form method="POST" autocomplete="off" class="form-signin">
                <div class="jumbotron text-center">
                    <h1>Register your account here with your Email id</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" name="firstName" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" placeholder="First name"/> <!-- Suggestions disabled -->
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" name="lastName" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Last name"/> <!-- Suggestions disabled -->
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="email" name="username" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Email id"/> <!-- Suggestions not disabled -->
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Password"/>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="password" name="passwordConfirm" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Confirm your password"/>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-success" type="submit">Register</button>
                    <a href="${contextPath}/loginEmployee">Back to login</a>
                </div>

            </form>

        </div>

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
         <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

        <!-- jQuery library -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
    </body>
</html>
```

We tried [How do we control web page caching, across all browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2068407/7218656) but still it is not working, then we assumed like it might be the `username` so we changed the field to

```
<input type="text" name="something" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Something">
```

Still suggestions are coming for the field.

If suggestions are disabled for first two fields why it is not done for Email-id?

PS : Browsers used **Mozilla Firefox 68.0.1** and **Chrome 75.0.3770.142**

Comment: What browser (and which version) do you use? Does it behave the same in other/all browsers? E.g. Chrome is well known of ignoring `autocomplete="off"` in some versions.

Comment: Chrome ignores this setting and prefills email and password. It is a big problem with chrome.

Comment: But even in Firefox it doesn't work and that too for certain fields

Comment: I have older FF (60.7.0esr) on Linux, and it works there. On the other hand, Chrome 75.0.3770.100 (Linux) ignores the attribute completely (for all the fields, not just e-mail).

Comment: @Jozef Chocholacek in my chrome suggestions for First name and Last name are disabled